# b10k minigame problems

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I tried to recreate a mini game (not sure about its name, I call it b10k) with 2048 looks, therefore it looked better if I use html elements, and I really am not good at working with them, but I tried: https://github.com/Cicada3301/b10k

I could also find out that there is a bug that sometimes doesn't update the player's position when going up or down. I suggest using [this](http://www.5minfork.com) for testing it on non-local machine.

Please insult me if it's constructive, and don't forget about code readability!
Could you also find out the reason of the glitch?

here is the JavaScript code for who don't want to click the link:

```
 function b10k() {
    var player,
        boardSide = 40,
        boardMargin = 2.5;
    function Level(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.size = this.map.length;
    }
    function Player(x, y, map, container) {
        this.x =x;
        this.y =y;
        this.map = map;
        this.container = container;
        this.el = document.getElementById('player');
        this.render();
    }
    Player.prototype.move = function (dir) {
        var nextBlock =  this.map[this.y + dir.y]? this.map[this.y+dir.y][this.x + dir.x]:undefined;
        if (nextBlock !== undefined&&nextBlock!==1) {
            this.x += dir.x;
            this.y += dir.y
            this.move(dir);
        } else {
            this.render();
        }
    }
    Player.prototype.render = function () {
        this.el.style.left = '' + ((this.x * (boardSide / this.map.length) + boardMargin) + 'vw');
        this.el.style.top = '' + ((this.y * (boardSide / this.map.length) + boardMargin) + 'vw');
    }
    Level.prototype.play = function () {
        this.render(document.getElementById('map'))
        this.adjustElements();
    }
    Level.prototype.adjustElements = function () {
        var player = document.getElementById('player');
        player.style.setProperty('width', (boardSide/2 / this.size) + 'vw');
        player.style.setProperty('height', (boardSide/2 / this.size) + 'vw');
        player.style.setProperty('margin', (boardSide/4 / this.size) + 'vw');
        var goal = document.getElementById('goal');
        goal.style.setProperty('width', (boardSide/2 / this.size) + 'vw');
        goal.style.setProperty('height', (boardSide/2 / this.size) + 'vw');
        goal.style.setProperty('margin', (boardSide/4 / this.size) + 'vw');
    }
    Level.prototype.render = function (container) {
        container.innerHTML = '';
        for (var row = 0; row < this.size; ++row) {
            container.innerHTML += '<tr id=row' + row + '></tr>';
            var currentRow = document.getElementById('row' + row);
            for (var col = 0; col < this.size; ++col) {
                var addition = '';
                switch (this.map[row][col]) {
                    case 1: addition = 'class="wall ';
                        var sides=['top-right ', 'bottom-right ', 'bottom-left ', 'top-left'];
                        if (this.map[row + 1]) { if (this.map[row + 1][col] === 1) sides[1] = sides[2] = ''; }
                            else sides[1] = sides[2] = '';
                        if (this.map[row - 1]) { if (this.map[row - 1][col] === 1) sides[0] = sides[3] = ''; }
                            else sides[0] = sides[3] = '';
                        if (this.map[row][col + 1] === 1 || this.map[row][col + 1] === undefined) sides[0] = sides[1] = '';
                        if (this.map[row][col - 1] === 1 || this.map[row][col - 1] === undefined) sides[2] = sides[3] = '';
                        addition += sides[0] + sides[1] + sides[2] + sides[3] + '"';
                        break;
                    case 2: addition = 'id="goal"'; break;
                    case 3: player = new Player(col, row, this.map, document.getElementById('game')); this.map[row][col] = 0;
                }
                currentRow.innerHTML += '<td ' + addition + ' style="top:' + (row * (boardSide / this.size) + boardMargin) + 'vw; left:' + (col * (boardSide / this.size) + boardMargin) + 'vw; width:' + (boardSide / this.size) + 'vw; height:' + (boardSide / this.size) + 'vw"></td>';
            }
        }
    }
    var levels = [
        new Level([
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]
            ])
    ];
    levels[0].play();
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        var isKey = true;
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37: player.move({x:-1, y:0}); break;
            case 38: player.move({x:0, y:-1}); break;
            case 39: player.move({x:1, y:0}); break;
            case 40: player.move({x:0, y:1}); break;
            default: isKey = false;
        }
        if (isKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    })
};
b10k();
```

html here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>b10k - towc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Welcome to the b10k game!</h1>
        <span id="level">1</span>
        <div id="game">
            <div id="player"></div>
            <div id="board"></div>
            <table id="cell-container">
                <tbody id="map"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="rules">
            <h2>Rules:</h2>
            <ol>
                <li>Press arrow keys to play</li>
                <li>Your goal is to get the green block in the red spot</li>
                <li>The green block only stops after hitting other blocks or margins</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally the css:

```
body {
    background-color:beige;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#container {
    margin-left:30vw;
}
#level::before {
    content: 'level ';
}
#game {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:lightgray;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin-left:-5vw;
    width:45vw;
    height:45vw;
}
#cell-container {
    width:40vw;
    height:40vw;
    margin:2.5vw;
    background-color:azure;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#cell-container td {
    position:absolute;
}
#rules {
    margin-top:60vw;
}
#player {
    background-color:green;
    margin:1vw;
    width:2vw;
    height:2vw;
    transition:top 0.4s, left 0.4s;
    border-radius:2px;
    position:absolute;
}
.wall {
    background-color:gray;
    width:4vw;
    height:4vw;
}
.bottom-left{
    border-bottom-left-radius:9px;
}
.bottom-right {
    border-bottom-right-radius:9px;
}
.top-left {
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
}
.top-right {
    border-top-right-radius:9px;
}
#goal {
    background-color:red;
    border-radius:3px;
    width:3vw;
    height:3vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll primarily do the JS:

- Spacing and code style: Everything is perfect except for one line.
- `if(this.map[this.y-1]) if (this.map[this.y-1][this.x] ===0){` - `if if`? Why not use `&&`? See **[short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)**
- Your `move*` methods are repetitive. Perhaps some abstraction is in order?
- Avoid magical constants - What's 40? What's 2.5?
- Lack of Documentation - Your `construct` method could really use it.

Also, if you're trying to move to the top or bottom layers, your `render()` method will never reach. You should add a check against `this.map[expected Y value]` to not be undefined.

Comment: "prevent" is very optimistic here.

Comment: the double if is to prevent code breaking. The first one is to prevent code breaking, since if it returns undefined the next if won't fire, if we check the second one and this.map[this.y-1] is undefined it will break the code. The && still operates both of the sides even if he sees that the first one is undefined

Comment: `&&` works the same way. If the first one is false, the second one will not execute.

Comment: the move methods are repetitive, but faster. I should make some variables describing what 40 and 2.5 are, going to do it now. What do you mean lack of documentation? Also, you can't access any of the variables in the game, it's all enclosed in a function which gives no access from the outside

Comment: also, you didn't find out why the glitch is there

Comment: It's not always perfectly clear what you are doing in your methods. Add some comments. As for the faster methods, how fast do you need them? You have O(n) complexity either way, and there's a transition on the move anyway by CSS. About the access, you are right. My bad.

Comment: Well, I already told you in chat why your glitch is there :P I can add it here as well if you'd like.

Comment: @towc Read about [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

Comment: also: if I remove the double if I will still have to check other 2 times if the specified blocks are undefined (edges)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I've updated the js based on what you said was wrong. What's the line you're talking about in the first point?